# Lots of users in the "Assigned To"` dropdown of work item, in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

When I want to assign a work item to a new person, there's a huge list of users in the combo box to select. Lots of them are gone from the company and are inactive in the domain control.

But the list shows all of them which makes it hard to select people.

How can I tell TFS not to show the inactive users in the assigned to list?

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed this before by creating a Project Collection group called 'Global Exclusion'.
Then I add non-existing users I don't want to display, including service accounts, from AD into this list.
When the list is populated with any AD account you don't want to display, just customize your work item to exclude the 'Global Exclusion' TFS group.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the periodical sync from `Active Directory` to `TFS` is broken, I found an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106895/Active-Directory-Groups-not-Syncing-with-Team-Foun) that could help you work your way through, it mentions that if the job fails, it sets the sync job to inactive, thus preventing any future updates.

Comment: The article identifies a problem that new users are not showing in TFS, not the problem that disabled users are still showing in the TFS list. The service is running correctly here.